# How insecure are PHP's rand functions?

Tags: cryptography, php, random

There are some pseudo-random-number generators in PHP: [rand()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php), [srand()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php), [mt_rand()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php), [mt_srand()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php). You can look at their code [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/rand.c).

I understand those functions are insecure, but how insecure are they?

For example, if those functions are used for generation of anti-CSRF tokens, tokens in file download links how easy will it be for attacker to guess those of other user? How he can do it?

**Update:** The paper [I Forgot Your Password: Randomness Attacks Against PHP
Applications](http://crypto.di.uoa.gr/CRYPTO.SEC/Randomness_Attacks_files/paper.pdf) seems to be a canonical reading on the subject and contains detailed response to this question. However, it's quiet long and complicated so I'd want to see a more short excerpt that will point or show existence of exploit algorithm using which those functions can be broken.

Comment: Duplicate of [How insecure are non-cryptographic random number generators?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17988/how-insecure-are-non-cryptographic-random-number-generators)

Comment: @Polynomial Not a duplicate. D.W. specifically said in comments that that question is too broad and more specific questions should be asked about other functions. I ask about weaknesses in those exact functions.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll provide an answer.

Comment: If you want more details on the attacks, I updated my answer with additional links that explain some of these attacks.  But do understand that some of the attacks do involve some mathematics.  That's just how it goes, sometimes.

Comment: *"I want to see a more short excerpt that will point or show existence of exploit algorithm using which those functions can be broken"* - The references already show a working attack algorithm, but it's not something you can fit in a fortune cookie. Sometimes attacks are complicated; that's just the way it is. (By the way, given the number of independent sources that state that these PRNGs are broken and insecure, and explain why, I think it would be wise to believe them.)

Answer (score 7):

PHP's `rand()` generator is a based on the system implementation, which is usually a weak LCG or LFSR (see Andrey's comment below). For more info on why these types of generators are bad, take a look at [How insecure are non-cryptographic random number generators?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17988/how-insecure-are-non-cryptographic-random-number-generators)

The `mt_rand()` function uses [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister), which isn't much better. You can determine the internal state and all future values after [observing just 624 values](http://eprint.iacr.org/2005/165.pdf).

Don't use either in any situation where you require cryptographic-strength randomness, including CSRF / password-equivilent tokens. A better alternative is the [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) function, or reading from `/dev/urandom`. You could also look into implementing [Blum Blum Shub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub), which is a strong (albeit slow) PRNG.

---

**EDIT (Feb 2017):** As of PHP7 the correct method to generate secure random bytes is the [`random_bytes()`](http://php.net/random_bytes) function. For more detailed advice about secure RNGs in a variety of languages, take a look at [this article](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/05/how-generate-secure-random-numbers-in-various-programming-languages#).

Comment: PHP's rand() uses internal system implementation. At Linux it's LFSR, not LCG. See section 5.4 in [this paper](http://crypto.di.uoa.gr/CRYPTO.SEC/Randomness_Attacks_files/paper.pdf) for more details

Comment: Whoops, I misunderstood then. I'll update.

Comment: Bruteforce attack that you outlined in your answer to linked question will be impractical because of state of glibc is 31 word of 32 bits each. Again, see section 5.4 in [this paper](http://crypto.di.uoa.gr/CRYPTO.SEC/Randomness_Attacks_files/paper.pdf)

Comment: @AndreyBotalov The bruteforce attack was only meant to be feasible for RNGs whose state is entirely determined from an initial seed. If an LFSR draws entropy from other sources, the bruteforce will be impossible.

Comment: Don't use Blum-Blum-Shub.  It is totally irrelevant here.  Recommending Blum-Blum-Shub is like recommending that the person use Diffie-Hellman: it doesn't solve the problem, and is misleading.

Comment: @Polynomial Do you propose to roll my own PHP implementation of Blum Blum Shub?

Comment: @AndreyBotalov Not until D.W. explains further. He knows more about this than me.

Comment: @D.W. Care to clarify? I though BBS was a decent CSPRNG?

Comment: @Polynomial, BBS requires a random seed.  This question asks where to obtain a random seed.  BBS does not solve that problem.  (BBS is like AES-CTR; it stretches a short seed to a long pseudorandom output.)  So BBS solves a totally different problem than we are discussing here.  [Incidentally, BBS is over-hyped. BBS gets hyped because of its "proof" of security.  However, I cannot think of any context where I would recommend BBS over, say, AES-CTR.  If you want more on that, please ask a separate question, as this subject is too long to explain in a comment.]

Comment: @D.W. Ah, yes, I didn't consider the seeding issue. I'll defer to your judgement on this one regarding BBS vs. AES-CTR; perhaps I'll open a question so you can express your wisdom on the matter! :)

Comment: Also OpenSSL is not very secure. See https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/07/how-safely-generate-random-strings-and-integers-in-php for a detailed explanation and better alternatives.

Comment: openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(...) has been criticized for using a 'home grown' method to collect random. *Please* recommend [random_bytes](http://php.net/random_bytes) instead.

Comment: @Jacco Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are now cryptographically secure pseudo-random generators in PHP 7, including [random_int](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) and [random_bytes](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php).  Might be worth checking those out.

Comment: Sorry, I've just realised how old this question/answer was!

Comment: Don't be sorry for adding new, relevant information to an old question. That is one of the reasons StackOverflow is so good: questions are never locked to prevent new information as it surfaces (so long as they follow the site guidelines). Your insight is valuable, thanks for posting.

Answer (score 2):

Those are all insecure.  None of them are suitable for use in a CSRF token, or any other application requiring cryptographic strength.  If you want more details why you should not use these methods, see the following resources:

- [I Forgot Your Password: Randomness Attacks Against PHP Applications](http://crypto.di.uoa.gr/CRYPTO.SEC/Randomness_Attacks_files/paper.pdf), George Argyros, Aggelos Kiayias, Black Hat USA 2012.
- [mt_srand and not so random numbers](http://www.suspekt.org/2008/08/17/mt_srand-and-not-so-random-numbers/)
- [Cryptographic security of PHP mt_rand() function using Mersenne Twister algo](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2231/351)

You should instead use `random_bytes()` or `/dev/urandom`.

See also [Better Random Numbers in PHP using /dev/urandom](http://codeascraft.etsy.com/2012/07/19/better-random-numbers-in-php-using-devurandom/).

Comment: The cross-platform implementation in PHP for crypto quality random is [random_bytes](http://php.net/random_bytes). On linux platforms it uses /dev/urandom as its source

Answer (score 2):

All of the PRNGs you listed are insecure.  Anything dealing with security (sessions, tokens, secrets) requires a CSPRNG.  Here are a list of suitable alternatives:

- mcrypt_create_iv() - Uses /dev/urandom on *NIX and the built-in crypto platform on Windows.  Requires the 'mcrypt' extension.
- /dev/urandom - Requires a *NIX host.
- openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() - Requires the 'openssl' extension.
- http://barebonescms.com/documentation/csprng/ - A cross-platform solution that uses whatever is available plus a number of trusted remote web hosts that generate true random data.

As to your question regarding the paper, whatever algorithm you might come up with to generate a random string has probably been done before and the source code is likely available somewhere.  If a PRNG is seeded with the current system clock in microsecond resolution, the search space is drastically reduced requiring only a few hundred thousand attempts.  Combine that with maybe a few hundred common algorithms and you're looking at potentially mere seconds of CPU to reverse-engineer a token and synchronize with a remote system clock.  After that, the application's security is hosed.

I guess the question is, will anyone care to hack your website at that level?  Finding a SQL injection opportunity is generally a much easier route than trying to reverse-engineer a token scheme.  Low-hanging fruit is more desirable to a hacker.

Comment: While `mcrypt_create_iv` is a good source of crypto-quality random, the MCrypt functions are abandonware, don't use them anymore. `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` has been criticized for using a 'home grown' method to collect random. Since PHP7, [`random_bytes`](http://php.net/random_bytes) is the preferred, cross-platform, source for crypto quality random. On linux platforms, it uses /dev/urandom as its source.